# Как проверить является ли введенная строка числом?

Tags: java, android

Есть ли какой-то булевый метод в java, который принимает строку и проверяет является ли она числом?Например имеем переменную `String var="2";`. И надо проверить можно ли ее перегнать в переменную числового типа(Например так `Integer.parseInt(var);`)

Comment: @Nofate Кстати говоря, ни в старом, ни в текущем вопросе нет варианта ответа "используйте commons-lang 'NumberUtils#isNumber'". А, между прочим, он учитывает очень многие особенности чисел в Java.

Comment: @EvgenyLazarev вы можете написать об этом в том вопросе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false; 
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
    // only got here if we didn't return false
    return true;
}
```

(c) [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java)